# how to Force close app swiftui and no recentes

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an app made with swiftui, is for ios

I want to force close the app and/or on .onReceive willResignActiveNotification and willEnterForegroundNotification do it

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
                    
                    exit(0);
                }
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
                    
                    exit(0);
                    }
                }
```

this isnt recomended, i know.

But the problem i have is that when opening the "App switcher" on simulator or iphone the app remains there and i can open it from there.

Any idea or solution?

i searched a lot and i dont know how to make that my app dont appear on "App switcher"

Comment: Why do you want to inconvenience your users?

Comment: AFAIK this will be rejected in AppStore.

Comment: Yes i know will be rejected, the app is only for me, not for publishing

Comment: The appearance of your app in the "recent app switcher" is not an indication of whether the app is running or not. This is why it is wrong for people to swipe away all of the apps in their app switcher. They think that iOS is windows 3.1 and all of those apps are running snd impacting their device, but they aren't. It is mostly just a history of apps that have run. If you want to change the snapshot that is shown in the app switcher, then that is a different thing. You need to update your view in response to the `willResignActive` state.

Comment: since it is your own app and it won't be published you can call `fatalError()`